# Breaking closed line when intersecting with polygon using SAGA GIS?

Tags: geoprocessing, saga, breaklines

I have a number of polygons (in lines shape) which represent the new condition of an area and a numder of polygons (in polygon shape) which represent the old condition of the same area.

How can I break the new polygons (line shape) at the point that intersect with the old polygons (polygon shape) using SAGA GIS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to complete this task by converting the polygons in lines and then I use the SAGA GIS and the tool *split Lines with Lines*.